# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception when reading tiff image

Tags: java, arrays, image, jpeg, tiff

I have codes here.(Classname=test2.java)

```
    final String filepath = "brabrabra.tif";
    final String jpg = filepath + ".jpg";
    ImageInputStream iis = null;

    iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(filepath));
    Iterator<ImageReader> ite = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
    if (ite != null && ite.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader reader = ite.next();
        reader.setInput(iis);
        int numPage = reader.getNumImages(true);
        IntStream.range(0, numPage).forEach(v -> {
        try {
            BufferedImage tiff = reader.read(v);
            ImageIO.write(tiff, "jpeg", new File(fullpathjpeg));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

and exception logs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1909
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFFaxDecompressor.decodeT6(TIFFFaxDecompressor.java:1169)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFFaxDecompressor.decodeRaw(TIFFFaxDecompressor.java:680)
at com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFDecompressor.decode(TIFFDecompressor.java:2514)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.decodeTile(TIFFImageReader.java:1137)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.read(TIFFImageReader.java:1417)
at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:939)
at test2.lambda$0(test2.java:44)
at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:559)
at test2.main(test2.java:41)
```

This line gave me an error

```
BufferedImage tiff = **reader.read(v);**
```

I don't know why I get this error. Curiously, almost all tiff files were read normally and converted into jpg files, but some were not. I compared tiff files between them but there is no specific difference.(of course I found some differences like size, byte and so on however I don't think those are not related to this error.

Can anyone give me help?

---

This file is the cause of the problem

[differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Tc8.png)

Comment: Try to make the 'tiff' variable as an array! I'm not sure about will it work or not, but give it a try..

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm not sure how to fix. I think tiff variables should be BufferedImage because reader.read(v) returns it

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc `getNumImages`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getNumImages(boolean)

It seems your problem might be expected behavior.

Comment: As per the docs `If images are to be processed in order, it may be more efficient to simply call read with increasing indices until an IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown to indicate` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getNumImages(boolean)

Comment: A problem tiff file has only 1 page and getNumImages just give 1(I debugged so it's sure). It seems that my error logs say TIFFFaxDecompressor.decodeT6(TIFFFaxDecompressor.java:1169)T6 is a root cause, doesn't it?

Comment: *"Curiously, almost all tiff files were read normally and converted into jpg files, but some were not."* - In this case, attach one of the TIFF files that failed with the above exception. The problem is the file, not the code.

Comment: Sorry tiff files include private informations so I can't show you. Those files doesn't look weird as long as I checked in photo viewer, displayed normally. I understand the problem is the file in this situation, but where can I find it

Comment: Without the file, it's hard to give more help... Try to see if you can reproduce the problem with an image that has no private information, or try to create such an image. You could also try to use a different TIFF plugin. I make one, that might help: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys

Comment: @HaraldK I'm gonna check your plugin out. Hopefully I could get a file without any information and attached to this topic. Please check.

Comment: Hmmm.. The attached `errorFile.tiff` is not really a TIFF. It's a PNG file. It can be read without problems (although it looks like the image data was lost in the conversion).

Comment: @HaraldK Via this site tiff files seems to be converted into png. I got a file of tiff-params and also attached an image of comparison. The left side is an error file(unreadable) and the right side is an normal file(readable). I see some params are different, probably some of them are causes.  This two images are originally same, but the difference between them is whether they are passed through formatting tool. The right side was formatted with tool from the left side,  however I gave no option(size, quality, and so on)   . I think the tool gave an error tiff params that it doesn't have

Comment: There's nothing wrong with any of these IFDs .The main difference is that the one to the left uses (unsurprisingly) CCITT.T6/G4 fax compression, while the other is uncompressed. The left one uses a single strip, the right one uses multiple strips. But both of them are completely fine. The exception you experience happens during decoding. Likely a bug/issue in either the encoder (PixTIFF) or the decoder (Java TIFF plugin). But without seeing the *actual image data*, I can't tell.

Comment: PS: I would also suggest posting listings like your "differences" image as text in the question, rather than an image, for better clarity and readability.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, it's really troublesome. But I discussed this problem with my teammembers and we decided not to convert tiff into jpeg if is has this issue. I can get a exception when this error occurs so it's easy to do so.  Thank you for kind reply.